# Entity Framework - Updating records shows annotations error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity

Here is Model for the Table.

```
public class Master
    {        
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string EmailId { get; set; }
        public string UniqueCode { get; set; }
....
        [Required]          
        public string Password { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [NotMapped]
        [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    }
```

When I try to Update the Above record with following Code, I get Validation Errors `The password and confirmation password do not match.` , `The confirmation password is required.`.

The confirmation password property is not mapped. How to set off annotations while updating the record?
 :-

```
 var data = ctx.tblMaster.Where(m => m.EmailId == emailId).Select(m => m).SingleOrDefault();
                    data.UniqueCode = UniqueCode;

                    ctx.tblMaster.Attach(data);
                    ctx.Entry(data).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done rather simply front end. The validation which occurs is done based on html5's data attribute. Remove the data attributes from an input element and the validation will cease to function.

You can conditionally remove fields in model state from controller like this

Example code:

```
  if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
  {
...

// We don't need to validate user fields if user is logged in.
ModelState.Remove("CommenterName");
ModelState.Remove("Email");
 }
```

Comment: This Code is written for Forgot Password, So in the View I just have Email Id Textbox option..

Comment: You can conditionally remove fields in model state from controller like Please see my updated code

Comment: As you can see from my code...i am passing just the email to the data layer & ModelState is not involved...& i get the data from db with email condition & then i am updating it...So is there any other solution??